# How to use Thread to run a class Constructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, eclipse-cdt

Is there a way to construct a class with specific parameters in a separate thread?

In the examples I have seen I can only see thread running functions and member functions. To be more specific, I would need it to run this constructor in a separate thread:

```
 Thermistor(ukd_Adc * pAdc,
            const lookup_table_t * pLUT,
            uint8_t numOfLutElements);
```

I want to construct the class in a different thread to assert functionality and check for edge cases.

If there is an edge case like the pointer to `ukd_Adc` being `NULL`, the assert will make it hang in an infinite loop. This thread will allow me to set a time limit on how long the constructor may run so it does not go into an infinite loop.

This is for testing purposes since google test does not have a timeout feature to my knowledge.

Comment: What do you mean by *"run a class constructor"*? A constructor is called when you create an instance of a class, regardless of whether it's in a multithreaded program or not

Comment: you can call the constructor inside a function. What would be the point of a thread that does nothing else than calling a constructor?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You think that the construction is going to be heavy and you want to defer it?

Comment: @tobi303 I need it to call the consturctor so I can time it in the main thread. I am testing edge cases now and one of the edge cases causes the constructor to go into an infinite loop so I am running the constructor in a seperate thread and ending the test after 5000 ms.

Comment: You can use `alarm()` or similar to set a timer without a separate thread.  That might make testing easier.

Comment: @JohnZwinck can you give me an example of how to use alarm()? I cannot find the documentation and am unfamiliar with it.

Comment: agree with John, adding another thread will make testing much harder rather than easier. Btw look at [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and note that often it is better to ask for the actual problem rather than asking about a possible solution you have in mind

Comment: @tobi303 I will take that advice about what question to ask into account for later. How would I time a function that goes into an infinite loop? Wouldn't the program get stuck at that function?

Comment: isnt that always taking an infinite amount of time? what do you want to measure?

Comment: @tobi303 I am unit testing the Thermistor class (with google test framework) so I need to make sure the function goes into an infinite loop. I need to eventually stop the constructor after it goes into an infinite loop so the rest of my tests can continue. My approach to this would to be to set a timer for 5 seconds and if it is not complete within that amount of time I know it is in an infinite loop and I stop it.

Comment: you cannot test for an infinite loop, thats the nature of infinity. Of course you can test if it takes more than 5 seconds, and actually in that case creating a seperate thread can be handy. However, then my first comment applies: if you know how to create a thread that calls a function then simply call the constructor inside a function. Wait for 5 seconds and check if the thread is still running

Comment: _the assert will make it hang in an infinite loop_ you have a funny assert.

Answer (score 3):

If you simply want to construct an object on a separate thread and check if it has successfully finished within a specific time constrain, use:

```
int main() { 
    std::promise<std::shared_ptr<Thermistor>> promise;
    std::future<std::shared_ptr<Thermistor>> future = promise.get_future();
    std::thread([&promise](ukd_Adc * pAdc,
                           const lookup_table_t * pLUT,
                           uint8_t numOfLutElements) {
      promise.set_value_at_thread_exit(std::make_shared<Thermistor>(pAdc, pLUT, numOfLutElements));
    }, <pAdc-value>, <pLUT-value>, <numOfLutElements-value>).detach();

    auto status = future.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
    if (status == std::future_status::ready)
    {
        // succeeded
    }
    else
    {
        // failed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`alarm()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/alarm.2.html) function to raise a signal (`SIGALRM`) after a specified amount of time:

```
static bool alarmed = false;
extern "C" void handler(int signo)
{
    alarmed = true;
}
signal(SIGALRM, handler);
alarm(5); // seconds to SIGALRM
// do stuff
// if (alarmed) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use pthreads start the process and when you don't like your thread anymore you can kill it off with [pthread_cancel](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html)

pseudo code

```
start thread
wait
cancel thread if not finished
```